# Distinct most recent data from database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am storing data in my database.  The data being stored looks like this

```
id  | upload_month | created_at
-----------------------------------------
1   | January      | 2017-01-30 13:22:39
-----------------------------------------
2   | Febuary      | 2017-01-30 13:23:42
-----------------------------------------
3   | January      | 2017-01-30 13:25:33
```

Within my Controller I am trying to retrieve the distinct upload_month, but get the latest inserted version for each.  At the moment I am trying

```
$uploadedFile = UploadedFile::groupBy('upload_month')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

The problem is that this is returning the following

```
id  | upload_month | created_at
-----------------------------------------
1   | January      | 2017-01-30 13:22:39
-----------------------------------------
2   | Febuary      | 2017-01-30 13:23:42
-----------------------------------------
```

So for the January record it is giving the older version.  If I change it to `->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')` it returns the same records but Febuary being the first row.

In essense, what I am after is this

```
id  | upload_month | created_at
-----------------------------------------
1   | January      | 2017-01-30 13:25:33
-----------------------------------------
2   | Febuary      | 2017-01-30 13:23:42
-----------------------------------------
```

How am I able to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#selects try the distinct method  https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_distinct ;)

Comment: The only reason I was not using distinct was because it is doing a raw DB query rather than using elequent

Comment: Eloquent doesn't make any query as I know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should `GROUP BY` all fields you want to select, no only one. This article explain the issue: https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

The proper SQL query in this case would be:

```
SELECT id, upload_month, created_at
  FROM uplodaded_file
  JOIN (SELECT upload_month, MAX(created_at) created_at
          FROM uplodaded_file
      GROUP BY upload_month) months
    ON upload_month = months.upload_month
   AND created_at = months.created_at
```

The eloquent version of this is a little bit tricky. It will be better to use a raw query in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the latest() method instead of orderBy:

```
UploadedFile::latest()->distinct()->get();
```

Comment: Unfortunatly that does not return the unique months.  I am being returned all 3 results.

Comment: try groupBy('upload_month') with latest.

Comment: Now it returns two months, but not the latest January one

Comment: try this UploadedFile::groupBy('upload_month')->latest()->distinct()->get();

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue and solved it this way.

```
UploadedFile::select(DB::raw('upload_month, MAX(created_at) as latest_date'))
->groupBy('upload_month')->orderBy('latest_date', 'desc')->get()
```

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.