# Laravel - use distinct on elequent

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get last three prices (6,7,8). **I don't need Limit.**

`id: 8` is an update from `id: 5`,

`id: 8` should show instead of `id: 5`

```
[
    {
        id: 5,
        product_id: 1,
        seller_id: 26,
        color_id: 18,
        warranty_id: 29,
        price: 1000000,
        created_at: "2017-05-27 09:33:44",
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        product_id: 1,
        seller_id: 26,
        color_id: 19,
        warranty_id: 30,
        price: 1200000,
        created_at: "2017-05-27 09:33:56",
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        product_id: 1,
        seller_id: 26,
        color_id: 21,
        warranty_id: 33,
        price: 900000,
        created_at: "2017-05-27 09:34:06",
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        product_id: 1,
        seller_id: 26,
        color_id: 18,
        warranty_id: 29,
        price: 600000,
        created_at: "2017-05-27 10:21:23",
    }
]
```

My try:

```
$product->get_prices()
->groupby(['product_id','color_id','warranty_id','seller_id'])
->latest()
->get();
 // 5,6,7,8
```

Product.php

```
function get_prices(){
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Price');
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code as images.

Answer (score 2):

### Collection version

You can use the `unique()` [collection method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-unique) here. As unique value I used a combination of the given ids (seller, product, warranty and color id) with a delimiter (which you can change if you want.

I used the `reverse()` function before, so the unique function will return the **last duplicates** instead of the first ones.

Then go for `take()` as usual :)

```
$product->get_prices()->get()->reverse()->unique(function ($item) {
    return $item['product_id'] . "|" . $item['seller_id'] . "|" .          
              $item['color_id'] . "|" . $item['warranty_id'];
})->take(3);
```

You can issue Eloquent Queries before using the given solution too:

```
$product->get_prices()->with("...")->where("....")
        ->get()->reverse()->unique(function ($item) {
            return $item['product_id'] . "|" . $item['seller_id'] . "|" .          
                   $item['color_id'] . "|" . $item['warranty_id'];
        })->take(3);
```

---

### ORM Version ?

I have tried a lot to get a working ORM version up, but unfortunately I couldn't manage to create one.
If you really want to do it on the DB layer, better use a raw query I guess.

Related:
[Distinct most recent data from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938658/distinct-most-recent-data-from-database)

Comment: but . we cant do it in orm ? ( on orm)

Comment: Well, it's harder to it it on ORM, then it is with collections IMO. I'm sure there is a way to do it with Eloquent only, but I don't think it performs better.

Comment: please take a look at my update, I prefer do it on ORM

Comment: Are there any reasons why you do prefer it through ORM? @danialdezfooli

Comment: for example there is 100 price of this product, and we need only 3 or 4 (unknown number)

Comment: @danialdezfooli As I mentioned above, I don't think that performance difference will be huge, because the "complex" queries of Eloquent will likely have the same execution time.

Comment: @danialdezfooli I've added a take call anyway :)

Comment: @danialdezfooli Updated my answer for using ORM-things again

Comment: Did you find any orm way :D ? : )

Comment: @danialdezfooli Unfortunately not. Anyway, I added a related question. So maybe a raw query would suffice here.